# implementing an SDK on android

Tags: android

I have some kind of voice related algorithm and I want android apps to be able to use it. I want multiple apps to be able to use it at the same time (it doesn't have to support multiple clients calling at once, but it does have to support multiple clients loading the library).
What is the best way to implement it? I read a little about bound services but I am not sure it fits. I can't extend the Binder class since I need multiple app support, and I don't want to use a Messenger since it only provides asynchronous access and I need synchronous access (I want to return an object from the call).
One other thing I don't understand is how to deliver my SDK. Should it be a library? an application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to implement it?

That is impossible to answer in the abstract.

> I can't extend the Binder class since I need multiple app support

Remote services using AIDL and Binder can support multiple apps.

> I don't want to use a Messenger since it only provides asynchronous access and I need synchronous access (I want to return an object from the call)

Returning data to a requester does not require synchronous access.

> One other thing I don't understand is how to deliver my SDK. Should it be a library? an application?

If you want multiple apps to use one single copy, it has to be its own application, which means the user will need to install your app separately. And, it means that changing your API is more painful, because you need to maintain backwards compatibility, since not all apps will update to your new API at the same time, and the user might not update all copies of their apps to your new API at the same time.

Personally, I would recommend you just make it be a JAR or Android library project, that each developer puts in their own project.